# почему docker пропускает udp трафик

Tags: docker, udp

Работая с образом стороннего приложения заметил странную на мой взгляд особенность: в контейнер попадает udp трафик(проверил wireshark`ом), хотя в параметрах запуска (-p)  я этого не указывал. Как это работает?
Приложение располагается в dockerhub: openvidu/openvidu-server-kms
C docker работаю не так давно, поэтому вопрос может быть глупым - сразу прошу прощения :)